# duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$ in paypal

Tags: ios, paypal, linker-errors

I am getting this error in paypal sdk 2.8.2 .

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPayment in:
>   ...libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalPayment.o)
>   ...libPayPalMPL.a(PayPalPayment.o) duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalPayment in:
>       ...libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalPayment.o)   ...libPayPalMPL.a(PayPalPayment.o) ld: 2 duplicate symbols for
>   architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

when i removed **`-ObjC`** in Other linker flags the error was solved . 
but  after that my  app crashes on pay button the log is :

```
-[PayPalPaymentViewController payPalServiceManager]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff2b5a38240
```

I have spent a whole day to solve it any help will be helpfull.

any help  can solve my day.....

Comment: Some libraries check for compiler flags and conditionally import different headers. Probably removing `-ObjC` is removing one of those imports. but I'm not sure why. I wish you could provide us with how you are including `PayPal SDK` and how you are importing its headers.

Comment: I have just use the paypal sdk using copy bundel resource and i am not using cocapods i am importing that library from pch file...

Comment: I was guessing that might be the reason! in your PCH you should always pay attention to the environment. you see, your PCH would get imported in every other header automatically, that mean those who may not be necessarily Objective-C, that's why you should check to see if the code is of ObjC (or check if foundation is defined and so). In a normal environment the `@import` would take care of duplicate imports but that directive is limited to objective-c code. I think your should import your paypal sdks inside an `#ifdef ObjC .... #endif` block

Comment: thanks for your support but #ifdef ObjC .... #endif in pch also give sane error ....cuold  you help me out

Comment: I'm doing my best to help you out, I hope you could consider using Cocoapods because it is much much easier to integrate and also maintain your dependencies but I can totally understand if you don't (because I didn't for over 2 years). Anyway, if you could post some code that'd be easier to help, especially the part in your PCH were you import PayPal sdk. And one more thing, It could help root out the problem if you could just import Paypal headers in the controllers you are going to use, instead of your PCH. could you test this scenario too?

Comment: I have tried pod also in that i have got the following error


diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.       I have install pod 4-5 times but unable to solve it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90285/discussion-between-nsdeveloper-and-m-porooshani).

Comment: i am importing in pch file
#ifdef ObjC ....

#import "PayPalPayment.h"
#import "PayPalAdvancedPayment.h"
#import "PayPalAmounts.h"
#import "PayPalReceiverAmounts.h"
#import "PayPalAddress.h"
#import "PayPalInvoiceItem.h"
#import "PayPal.h"
#import "PayPalMobile.h"

#import "PayPalPayment.h"
#import "PayPalInvoiceItem.h"
#import "PayPalMobile.h"

#import "PayPalConfiguration.h"
#import "PayPalPayment.h"



 #endif  same thing i have tried in my viewcontroller.m file